# bootstrap grid not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

On the picture is right side of my site. Some elements out from bootstrap grid.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#" class="logo">First</a>
      <nav class="main_menu clearfix">
        <button class="main_menu_button hidden-md hidden-lg"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why element nav can out from bootstrap grid? My main part is gray

Comment: Are you using any custom CSS?  Can you provide a better HTML and any custom CSS you are using.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 4):

Not really sure what is wrong with your markup or style, it's hard to understand from the given content, but you should put `.col-md-12` inside of `.row` not the other way around.

Here are some examples: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely familiarize yourself with how the HTML and CSS classes should be structured with bootstrap. You will need to start with a container class(eg. class="container"). Inside the container goes rows (class="row"), and inside the rows is your columns(eg. class="col-md-12").

Check out this page: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

If you are looking to build a nav out in bootstrap you do not necessarily need to re-invent the wheel and can use their Navbar Template: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Possibly something like this would work for you:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <a href="#" class="logo">First</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <nav class="main_menu clearfix">
            <button class="main_menu_button hidden-md hidden-lg">menu</button>
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @andrey1567 did this answer your question? Wondering if you are still looking for something else or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using bootstrap4 class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="brand" href="#">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
<ul class="nav navbar">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">career</li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">about</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

in case of you want to have vertical navigation then in nav tag remove the navbar-expand class.